# How can we use onclick event in controller file and use it as props in web file it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, sonarqube

I need to use onclick event as props in my code

Like this

{...this.handlechange} in controller file in React Typescript class components

And in web file I need to send props like this

<Button value={value} {...this.handlechange}> Next

And also I fails in sonar cube test

If anyone solve this , thanks in advance

I tried with this one

```
{...this.handlechange} in web file
```

Comment: this is an anti pattern. Declare your onclick as onClick={this.handlechange}

Comment: I tried both. Is there any other option that I can use as {...this.handleChange}

Comment: Why would that work? handleChange is a function not an array

Comment: In my project, they are using it for react native , and react js as well , its working for them but not for me,

Comment: Spread operator spreads an array. So if it works for them - handleChange is an array not a function. Or they are doing {...handleChange()} and the output of handleChange is an array